# How to install and run redis-server on windows machine(10 to be specific)?

Tags: node.js, windows, redis, redis-server

I am trying to create a sample application using redis. I am trying to install and run redis-server but I am getting this error:

```
$ redis-server
sh: redis-server: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis is not officially supported on Windows, but there is an [MSOpen Tech Native Redis Port](https://github.com/msopentech/redis) available.

Follow the instructions there to install redis, and your `redis-server` command should work.

You can also go to the [MSOpenTech Redis Release Page](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases) and download the `.msi` file for the latest release (one click install).

Comment: I cant find the steps for installation.

Comment: Follow the instructions under "How to build Redis using Visual Studio".

Comment: Is there any other way to install bcoz I don't have visual studio on my machine?

Comment: See additional comments above.